# Adding Haversine results to dataset as a double type

Tags: r, calculated-columns, dplyr, haversine

I would like to add a new column to a dataset containing the distance of each ride. To compute such distance I am using the given coordinates of the start and end of each trip using the haversine formula.

I am succeeding at computing the distance but struggling at adding that column to the data in a way I can read it.

Without adding the column, I get a temporary column (ride_distance) of type double (as I desire) showing the values as shown below:

```
filtered_dataset %>% rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(ride_distance=distHaversine(c(start_lon, start_lat), c(end_lon, end_lat)))
```

[image]

What I get when trying to add that column to the data I get this added instead:

```
filtered_dataset$ride_distance <- filtered_dataset %>%
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(distHaversine(c(start_lon, start_lat), c(end_lon, end_lat)))
```

[image]

Reading in the values of that column with head() I get this instead and they don't even show to be the same values...:
[image]

**How could I add my distance values to the data as doubles so I can keep using it for computations?**

Comment: Can you share a piece of your data set by `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: You already have the answer. You need to assign the value back to the dataset and not one column. `filtered_dataset <- filtered_dataset %>% rowwise()  %>% mutate(ride_distance=distHaversine(c(start_lon, start_lat), c(end_lon, end_lat)))`. `filtered_dataset <- ` is what you were missing.

Comment: @RonakShah, post as answer?  (Is there a canonical duplicate for "I failed to assign the result back to the original variable name" ?)

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing data frames (tibbles) with columns of tibbles.

This code:

```r
filtered_dataset %>%
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(ride_distance = distHaversine(c(start_lon, start_lat), c(end_lon, end_lat)))
```

produces the output you want; if you re-assign it to `filtered_dataset` (i.e. `filtered_dataset <- filtered_dataset %>% ...`) you'll get what you want.  You could also use the `%<>%` operator from the magrittr package, which assigns and pipes at the same time: `filtered_dataset %<>% rowwise() %>% ...`

Alternatively

```
filtered_dataset$ride_distance <- filtered_dataset %>%
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(x = distHaversine(c(start_lon, start_lat), c(end_lon, end_lat))) %>%
   pull(x)
```

would work.